# Сохранение данных из ckeditor в бд drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой - в самописном модуле под drupal 7 вместо textarea попросили установить полноценный редактор, после подключения редактора при попытке сохранить друпал выдает следующую ошибку:

> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1: INSERT INTO {holidays} (name, holiday_text, holiday_image, holiday_active, start_date, finish_date) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => testa_test [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 23243 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 2 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 2015-06-07 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 2015-06-08 [:db_insert_placeholder_1_0] =>
>
> testa_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_testtesta_test
>
> [:db_insert_placeholder_1_1] => html )

Т.е из вышеперечисленного становится понятно что редактор передает не только текст, но и формат текста, и следовательно передается на одно значение больше. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить данное недоразуменее?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

раньше элемент имел скалярное значение а теперь там теперь массив array('value' => '', 'format' => '')

Comment: да, я понял что там передается массив данных, но каким образом сохранить данный массив, запись в бд происходит таким образом:   db_insert('holidays')
  ->fields(array('name' => $form_state['values']['name'], 'holiday_text' => $form_state['values']['holiday_text'], 'holiday_image' => $form_state['values']['holiday_image'], 'holiday_active' => $form_state['values']['holiday_active'], 'start_date' => $start_date, 'finish_date' => $finish_date))
  ->execute();

Comment: если цкедитор для holiday_text то $form_state['values']['holiday_text']['value'] и наверное придется добавить столбец для хранения формата текста и передавать его в запрос как $form_state['values']['holiday_text']['format']

Comment: да, спасибо, $form_state['values']['holiday_text']['value'] - запись прошла, для формата не понадобилось добавлять столбца